# How can I control a list of applications in "Share" pop up in Android built in browser?

Tags: stock-browser, share-menu

I'm using Android's built in stock web browser (Froyo 2.2 if it matters), and when I choose "Share page" from the menu, I get a list of like 15 different apps.

Of those, I only ever use 2-3, and 99% of the time I use Gmail, which happens to be near the end of the list.

1. How does Android browser compile that list?
2. Is there a way to:

   - Control which applications appear in the list?
   - Sort the list the way I would want to?

The phone is rooted, so I'm perfectly fine if the answer is "Get a file from filesystem in this location and edit its contents".

Also, I don't necessarily need the answer to be 100% permanent - meaning, that if installing an application update will re-add the app to the list, I can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

This list is generated (on every boot) from the installed apps that have registered themselves with the system to handle this function.  The only certain way to remove an entry from this list is to  uninstall the corresponding app.

You can try de-compiling the app, removing the share intent from its "manifest.xml" file, and re-packing it.  However, this will most likely cause issues with Market updates because of signature mismatches.

Comment: Is the data read straight from the app's manifest.xml file? Or copied to some central DB?